# Regex to wrap JSON property value inside another string

Tags: regex

```
{ "url": "products/Sensors.html",
  "thumbnailUrl":"/images/icons/no_image.png",
  "translatedTitle": "sensors",
  ...
},
...
```

I would like to additional value "localhost:8080" to the property "thumbnailUrl" which ends with .png|jpg etc

replaced value should be as :

```
{ "url": "products/Sensors.html",
  "thumbnailUrl":"localhost:8080/images/icons/no_image.png",
  "translatedTitle": "sensors",
  ...
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: I have nominated to close this question as "too broad", as it does not include any attempt to solve the problem by the OP, or even basic information about which platform or language to do this for, even though the [tag:regex] tag wiki specifically asks for such details.  Anyway, using regex to manipulate structured formats is a huge anti-pattern.  Use a proper JSON tool instead.

Comment: Regular expressions are a formalism for pattern matching, and as such does not include any facility for substitution.  Many regex tools also have substitution facilities, but these are not standardized; there is no way to properly answer this question strictly as a [tag:regex] question, and the OP did not supply information about acceptable platforms or tools.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just do
    Myobj.thumbnailUrl = "localhost:8080" + myobj.thumbnailUrl;

Otherwise
    Mynewstring = myexistingstring.replace(/(thumbnailUrl\":\")/,'$1'+'localhost:8080');