# regex to replace the value of a key in a json file

Tags: java, regex

I want to make a regex so I can do a "Search/Replace" over a json file with many object. Every object has a key named "resource" containing a URL.

Take a look at these examples:

"resource":"/designs/123/image.jpg"

"resource":"/designs/221/elephant.gif"

"resource":"/designs/icon.png"

I want to make a regex to replace the whole url with a string like this: localhost:8080/filepath.

This way, the result would be:

"resource":"localhost:8080/designs/123/image.jpg"

"resource":"localhost:8080/designs/221/elephant.gif"

"resource":"localhost:8080/designs/icon.png"

I'm just starting with regular expressions and I'm completely lost. I was thinking that one valid idea would be to write something starting with this pattern "resource":"

How could I write the regular expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to wrap JSON property value inside another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007695/regex-to-wrap-json-property-value-inside-another-string)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is probably just to replace "resource":"/ with "resource":"localhost:8080/. You don't even need a regex for this (but if you do you just have to escape some stuff).

Answer (score -1):

With vim this would be

```
:%s/"resource":"\(.*\)"/"resource":"localhost:8080\1"
```

this should be easily transferable to java.